# SQL Query - displaying common rows based on conditions

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables namely ***TABLE1*** and ***TABLE2***
I am unable to understand how can I extract information from these two tables depending on a few conditions. Here is what I need basically:

I would like to get certain rows from the first ***TABLE1*** depending on the column value. There is a column named ***timecreated*** in ***TABLE1***. I would like to display all the rows in ***TABLE1*** which have been created in the last 30 days (the time is in UNIX timestamp) only when the following conditions are met:

1. COLUMN1='\core\event\course_viewed'    ***OR***
2. COLUMN2='\core\event\enrol_instance_created'    ***OR***
3. COLUMN3='restore'

Now ***TABLE2*** have columns named: ***ID, fullname and shortname***. I need to display these as well
The column ***ID*** in ***TABLE2*** is the same value as a column named ***courseid*** in ***TABLE1***. I would like to display those rows with ***fullname*** and ***shortname*** which corresponds to ***courseid*** which is named ***ID*** in ***TABLE1***.

What have I tried? I tried the following but it seems not to work

```
SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.* FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE 
(
TABLE1.COLUMN1 = '\core\event\course_viewed'
OR
TABLE1.COLUMN2 = '\core\event\enrol_instance_created'
OR
TABLE1.COLUMN3 = 'restore'
)
AND
TABLE2.COLUMN1 = TABLE1.COLUMN4
```

[image: TABLE1]
Sample Table 1

[image: TABLE2]

Sample Table 2

[image: DESIRED OUTCOME]
Desired Outcome table

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and desired output for this data.

Comment: No. the data must be not a picture but formatted textual code. I should copy it into the online fiddle.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Please in code questions give a [mre]. Put what is needed to ask in your psts, not just at a link. [ask] Clarify via edits, not comments. [help]  A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly". PS MySQL <> MariaDB. Pick one. PS Put the title before the thing it labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two improvements which would make your query work.

- When search for `\` you have to escape it i.e. If you want to search `app\user`, put `app\\user` in where clause.
- Use `INNER JOIN` if `courseid` always exists in `table1` otherwise `LEFT JOIN`, which clears the idea that we're working mainly on table1.

Having said that, following should work in your case.

```sql
SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.* 
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.id = TABLE1.courseid
WHERE TABLE1.timecreated >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    AND (
        TABLE1.COLUMN1 = '\\core\\event\\course_viewed'
        OR TABLE1.COLUMN2 = '\\core\\event\\enrol_instance_created'
        OR TABLE1.COLUMN3 = 'restore'
    )
```